# Не создается андроид проект в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Не создается проект андроид. При нажатии "Next" окно немножко трясется, и ничего не происходит. Идея при этом пишет ошибку: "Exception in plugin Android Support". Как лечить?
[image: Окошко]

Comment: Я бы посоветовал использовать AndroidStudio. Просто Idea не всегда поддерживает работу с андроидом корректно.

Comment: С андроид студио проблем нет. Нужно настроить именно идею.

Comment: Я однажды это пробовал и проблема была в отсутствии поддержки IDEA последней версии плагина градла. Попробуйте в эту сторону посмотреть. А вообще - странная у вас задача. Зачем вам нужно именно в IDEA что-то делать? Это глючно и неудобно и неработает)

Answer (score 0):

Может быть и не то, но  у меня была похожая проблема, окно тряслось и проект не создавался, только ошибок не было. Оказалось, что нужно было указать папку проекта, которая ещё не существует, чтобы он сам её создал.